# Pass value to parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

essentially I have a form component for users to fill out. When they complete an action: `onChange={onChange}` it returns a value (child component);

```
function onChange(value) {
  console.log("This is: ", value);
}
```

I want to pass the value to a state in the parent component (*so that the from can be processed and form data sent*). How can I do this? My constructor looks something like this (parent component);

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    form: {
      name: '',
      age: '',
      value: ''
    }
  };
}
```

Trying to learn react, please go easy as I'm unsure of how to do this. Would love any feedback! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Please read the official documentation [start guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html) carefully and patiently when you are a starter.

In react component, *state* is the internal state and *props* is the state passed from outside.

You could only modify the state by setState method.

As for the question you ask, you could define a callback function which call setState in parent component, then pass the callback function as props into the child component.

Answer (score 1):

As Zhili said, you should define a function in your parent component that is passed as prop to the child component.
Here's a brief example:

```
const Child = ({ onSubmit }) => (
  <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
    { /* your <input/>'s here ... */}
  </form>
);

class Parent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: null,
  };

  onChildSubmit = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div class="Something">
        <Child onSubmit={} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```